# Cannot unlock screen in iOS device (Simulator)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, automated-tests, appium, unlock

I'm trying to lock / unlock iOS simulator's device

```
driver.lockScreen(10);
```

Does the job , but the thing is , after the timeout (10s) the device hasn't been unlocked

It stays i locked state.

The appium log :

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/0d80a422-aadb-47db-a1cd-2a269226756e/appium/device/lock {"seconds":10}

info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.lock(10)"

info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.lock(10)

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:16 +0000 Debug: Got new command 9 from instruments: au.lock(10)

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:16 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.lock(10)

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:16 +0000 Debug: target.lockForDuration("10")

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:27 +0000 Debug: target.springboard().mainWindow().scrollViews().firstWithPredicate("ANY elements.name == 'SlideToUnlock' OR ANY elements.name == 'SlideToSetup'").dragInsideWithOptions({endOffset:{x:0.90,y:0.90}}, duration:"0.5", startOffset:{x:0.10,y:0.90}}})

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:29 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:29 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] [INST] 2015-08-06 14:50:29 +0000 Debug: Running system command #10: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":false}...
```

Any idea how to unlock the screen ? or what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: which ios version are you trying?

Comment: appium 1.4.8, java_client 3.1.0, IOS7.1 iphone 5s